# Можно ли извне читать память (запущеные процесы) виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox

есть программа которая постоянно сканирует запущенные процесы в поиске тех что в черном списке, защитит ли запуск в виртуалке (VirtualBox) программы из черного списка от обнаружения?

Comment: разумеется. сканер же смотрит таблицу процессов своей ОС. А в виртуалке своя собственная ОС, для хост системы являющаяся просто одним процессом

Comment: а нету там опции какойто чтобы шифровать содержимое процесов виртуалки?

Comment: а как процессор будет выполнять зашифрованный код ? на лету его расшифровывать  невозмножно, будет работать со скоростью 80286

Comment: жаль, спасибо за ответ